# best way for identifying changes on a dynamically created xml

Tags: php, xml, event-handling

Rest of my web service is on PHP but specific language requirement is not necessary.

So, what I would like to do is fairly simple - a dynamically updated xml is created by another API, and I have access to it. The xml contains information on live updates of some services (for example tube status etc).

I want to know whether there has been a change for specific events.

What I have done so far is this :

1. I am having a cron job which checks the xml every minute
2. And based on some conditions I know whether the update I am looking for has happened

But I do not like that option due to 1 - my server is constantly running. I am not using any frameworks or anything - just plain PHP.

Can I change that into something else? I am doing some preliminary reading on event based programming. Do you think this can be applied in this case? The trigger of the event will be the detection of the update I am looking into (already have that function for checking that), listener could be what I do when I detect that update and the source to be the xml or the parsed xml.

Do you see any potential improvement doing that?

Or maybe another language can work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I change that into something else?

Unless the API doesn't offer anything else (like an updates feed), you're pretty much bound to detecting the updates you own.

> I am doing some preliminary reading on event based programming. Do you think this can be applied in this case?

Sure.

> The trigger of the event will be the detection of the update I am looking into (already have that function for checking that), listener could be what I do when I detect that update and the source to be the xml or the parsed xml.

Sounds well thought.

> Do you see any potential improvement doing that?

Yes I do. The benefit is that you now can make other parts of your software listen to events.

Improvements in the detection of changes can be done by identifying segments in the XML and improve change detection with hashes, compare:

- [pulling xml feed and detecting changes/deletion php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13930485/367456)

> Or maybe another language can work better?

Yes, maybe that is the case. But stick to a language you can work with.